# Mongoose findandUpdate multiple field of document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to update multiple fields of a document:

```
 Game.findByIdAndUpdate(gameId, {
    $addToSet: {
        players: player.id
    },
    $addToSet: {
        playersInfo: player
    }, function(err, model){...}
}
```

But this query only executes my last `$addToSet`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JavaScript an object cannot have the same key multiple times. So the second overwrites the first.

Try this:

```
Game.findByIdAndUpdate(gameId, {
    $addToSet: {
        players: player.id,
        playersInfo: player
    }, function(err, model){...}
})
```